# Can a programmer damage micro-controllers?

Tags: avr

There is a question that can micro-controllers programmer damage micro-controllers in a way that they can't be programmed any more? (I have usb programmer)
This question came in my mind when i found out that my new-bought micro-controllers become unprogrammable after that i programmed them for some times, but except that they can't be programmed any more they work correctly in the way they have been programmed.
Thanks for reading.

Comment: That is pretty unlikely. It could probably happen, if the programmer itself is somehow faulty in a weird way.

Comment: Did you check the fuse settings of your micro-controllers ? Some might be set and unable the micro-controller to be programmable.

Comment: Yes i have checked, I have set micro-controller on internal calibrated oscillator , when This happens they are programmed like before and i think that nothing new happens to fuses.

Answer (score 2):

If your AVR has power issues during programming, it is possible for its fuse bits to become messed up.  You should make sure your batteries are fully charged (if applicable) and be careful not to disconnect power during programming.

If the AVR fuse bits that specify its clock source get corrupted and the AVR expects you to connect an external clock or crystal, but you do not have such a clock or crystal in your circuit, then the AVR will not have a clock signal and you be unable to program it.

Luckily, there is actually a way to revive such AVRs: you can get another microcontroller to generate a PWM signal and apply it to the XTAL2 or XTAL1 pin of your AVR as a low-speed clock signal (e.g. 100 kHz).  Then use your programmer (configured to use a low enough ISP frequency like 2 kHz) to connect to the AVR and fix its fuse bits so it uses the correct clock source.

The [Pololu USB AVR Programmer v2.1](https://www.pololu.com/product/3172) has a feature to generate such clock signals.  A procedure for reviving AVRs is documented in the "Using the clock output to revive AVRs" of that programmer's [user's guide](https://www.pololu.com/docs/0J67).  There is at least one person who successfully [revived an AVR](https://forum.pololu.com/t/3pi-dead-after-presumable-power-loss-during-flash/14441) using this principle.  If you try it, please let me know whether it works for you!

In general, there are lots of other ways for microcontrollers to be damaged or destroyed depending on what you are doing, so you might consider posting the details of your setup to a more AVR-focused forum that allows free-form discussion instead of just a question/answer format.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful post, but I am pretty sure that fuse bits that are related to clock setting are not changed because when i plug it without any external clock or oscillator it works as it has been programmed. So this means that it is set on internal oscillator.

Comment: And that my case is a bit different of what you said. So I don't think that the way above can help someway. I am not sure but if i suppose that it is locked accidentally, how can i unlock it?

Comment: Oops, I overlooked that part of your original question.  In that case I don't have any promising ideas about what is wrong or what you might do about it.